# Best approach for scheduling tasks on interval basis from database

Tags: mongodb, asynchronous, cron, redis, scheduling

I have a MongoDB collection with Tasks. Each task has an interval in seconds, Task identifier and payload that should be sent via HTTP POST to gather results and store them into another collection.

It may be thousands tasks with different intervals and I cannot figure out how to schedule them.

Currently I'm using simple polling by last execution time every 10ms but it produces heavy load on DB.

and it looks like this

```
mongo.MongoClient.connect(MONGO_URL, (err, db) ->
  handle_error(err)

  schedule = (collection) ->
collection.find({isEnabled:true, '$where': '((new Date()).getTime() - this.timestamp) > (this.checkInterval * 60 * 1000)'}).toArray((err, docs) ->
  handle_error(err)
  for i, doc of docs
    collection.update({_id: doc._id}, {'$set': {timestamp: (new Date()).getTime()}}, {w: 1})
        task = prepare(doc)
        request.post({url: url, formData: {task: JSON.stringify(prepare(doc))}}, (err,httpResponse,body) ->
          result = JSON.parse(body)
          console.log(result)
          db.collection(MONGO_COLLECTION_RESULTS).save({
        task: result.id,
        type: result.type,
        data: result
          })
        )

      setTimeout((() -> schedule(collection)), 10)
    )

  setTimeout((() -> schedule(db.collection(MONGO_COLLECTION_TASKS))), 10)
)
```

tasks can be added, updated, deleted and I have to handle it.
what about using redis? but I have no clue how to sync the data from mongo to redis when some tasks are waiting for result, interval was changed, etc

please advice best strategy for that

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the right way to solve your use case.

I would suggest to not store the tasks in whatever database but schedule them directly when they come in and save the result, with or without the original task information.

Why not use [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) to schedule the task?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the tasks to be run, you can schedule with the unix `crontab`, which runs a script that connects to DB or send HTTP requests.

If each task is unique, and you cannot pre-schedule them that way, perhaps you can use your current db collections, but not poll the db that often.

If it is not critical that the tasks are executed exactly on the right time, I would do a db lookup maybe once every 10 sec to see what tasks should have been executed since the last lookup.

One way of solving the db load would be to make a query that fetches tasks ordered on when they should be executed, with all tasks that should be executed within the next minute or so. Then you have (hopefully) a low amount of tasks in memory, and can set a javascript timeout for when they should be run. If too many tasks should be run at the same time, this could be problematic to fetch from the db at once.

The essence is to batch several tasks from the db into memory, and handle some of the scheduling there.